# When can you add two infinite series term by term?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a= \sum_{n \geq 1}a_n $and $b=\sum_{n \geq 1}b_n$. When can I say that $$a+b = \sum_{n \geq 1}a_n + b_n$$
?

What if all the terms were positive? Or do I need some absolute convergence?

Comment: Recall that a series is merely the limit of a sequence. When is the sum of the limits equal to the limit of the sum?

Comment: Always... I thought there is a way to rearrange the series to make $\sum a_n + b_n$ but I think this would require $\sum a_n + b_{f(n)}$. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to rearrange it. You just need to add their partial sums. So it is valid, if both series converge.